# How can I force a refresh of all tables in a workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I have a workbook with the following:

1. Schedule of students to teachers
2. Table of all of this data that I defined as a range called Database
3. Individual student sheets where the Database table witha filter for just that person's name.

When the user updates the schedule and prints the student sheets they are not updated with the new values from the schedule.

When they navigate to the individual sheet the data is old.  When they then choose the filter again the data is fine.

There are about 30 tables in this solution.  Is there a way force the refresh of these tables all at once?

What is the best way to ensure that the tables are automatically updated to reflect the new content.

I added navigation buttons with code to do an .AutoFilter.ApplyFilter, however, sometimes the users will just go to the sheet, or print all, thus not triggering that code.

Comment: does this work? https://analysistabs.com/vba-code/workbook/m/refreshall/#bm3

Comment: ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll